# Why the projection system and units are showing differ in ArcGIS and Autodesk AutoCAD Civil3D?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, autocad, civil3d

I have converted a bunch of shapefiles to .dwg through Model Builder in ArcGIS. The units and projection system is showing correctly in ArcGIS properties but in Autodesk Civil3D units are showing in feet and the projection system is showing no values for the same files.

What is the reason and how can I make it correct?

[image: Projection system and unit values from Arcgis:]

[image: Projection system and unit values from Autodesk Civil3D:]

Comment: for AutoCAD 3D/Civil you need to use _MAPIMPORT or _MAPCONNECT for the shapefile and .prj

Comment: These commands are required to open shp in civil3d, My questions is when I am opening a dwg which is converted by export to CAD tool under conversion tool, those dwgs are not showing units and projections in civil3d.

Answer (score 1):

I created a blank seed file of the drawing file and assigned unit meters and projection system sweref99 12 00 to it. While running a model in the setting of export cad, given seed file as an optional, after that all converted .dwg files are having correct unit and projection system.

[image]